# Dynamic images linked to url and page content

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I'm trying to build a webcomic format to display images and text content (not trying to promote my website this is just the current version of the what I have [basic format example](http://collapsinguniverse.com/archive) ).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPyV8.png]

the problem I'm having is trying to determine the best way to display the content at current for the pages.php :

```
<?php echo $page['pic']; ?> //where pic should be

<div id="page">

            <div class="container">

                <h1><?php echo $page['header']; ?></h1>

                <?php echo $page['body_formatted']; ?> <!-- text-->

    </div>
```

and in the database I have

`id - medint
   user - medint
   type - medint
   slug - varchar
   label - varchar
   'pic' - (??? type) was wondering if I could id a pic or put path here
   title - varchar
   header - varchar
   body - longtext`

I'm trying to keep the data all together (but I considered having a seperate table for just images, but if the webcomic is going to be 5000+ images I want to keep it simple structure as pages increase.) How should I go about having this format:

`image
 header}
 body  }`

with main image separate from header and body? (sorry I'm still learning how best to do this)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get the point really. Could you please clearify your question? One thing I can say by now is that you should think about storing your images in the file system, not in DB. This allows for static delivery, which keeps server performance low.

Comment: I can't get your point. Could you be more specific?